# Ошибка при установке библиотеки

Tags: python, pip

Использую pip чтобы установить библиотеку в своё виртуальное окружение и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Учебные материалы\EY\task_1\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "D:\Учебные материалы\EY\task_1\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 384, in run
      installed = install_given_reqs(
    File "D:\Учебные материалы\EY\task_1\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 53, in install_given_reqs
      requirement.install(
    File "D:\Учебные материалы\EY\task_1\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 981, in install
      os.path.relpath(prepend_root(filename), egg_info_dir)
    File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 703, in relpath
      raise ValueError("path is on mount %r, start on mount %r" % (
  ValueError: path is on mount 'D:', start on mount 'C:'


    ----------------------------------------
    Command ""D:\Учебные материалы\EY\task_1\Scripts\python.exe" "D:\Учебные материалы\EY\task_1\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip" install
     --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1fz2t00m\overlay
     --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- "setuptools >= 40.8.0"
     wheel "Cython >= 3.0a5" "cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation
 == 'CPython'" "greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'"" failed with error code 2 in None
```

Погуглив, узнал, что проблема с корневыми директориями, но так и не разобрался, в чем конкретно.

Comment: Сама команда была pip install gevent. Начал думать, что что-то не так с моим pip или настройками venv, но команда pip install tornado прошла успешно

Answer (score 0):

Загрузите предварительно скомпилированные пакеты здесь:

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent
```

(если я правильно понимаю)